mcf2graph.mp not found (TeXlive)
I tried to use mcf2graph with metapost but I get the following error:
! I can't open file `mcf2graph'.
l.1 input mcf2graph
                   ;


with the following code:
input mcf2graph;
sw_output:=Fig;
outputformat:="png"; hppp:=vppp:=0.01;
outputtemplate:="c%3c.png";

beginfigm
% EN:Ampicillin MW:349.405
\(<45,?4,-3=?5,2:N,7:S,
3^45:/*H,1://O^15,5:/*COOH^-18,6:??,
@4,*\^15,NH,!,//O,!,/*NH2,!,Ph)
endfigm

end.

Searching for the file, I found it in /install/path/of/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/doc/metapost/mcf2graph/ so it is normal that mpost does not find it.
Is it a problem with my install, or is that a problem with TeXlive?
Thanks.

Might have been a mistake when packing for texlive.

I've sent an email to the texlive mailing list

as you may have found, as a temporary workaround, you could copy the missing file from ../texlive/2024/texmf-dist/doc/metapost/mcf2graph/mcf2graph.mp to a local texmf tree.  On my mac I copied it to ~/Library/texmf/metapost/mcf2graph to make it work.

I put mcfgraph.mp and main_lib.mcf in the runtime for tonight's TL update.
